# Problem 5.10 Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are complex differentiable functions on $(0,1)$, $f(x) \rightarrow 0$, $g(x) \rightarrow 0$, $f'(x) \rightarrow A$, $g'(x) \rightarrow B$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, where $A$ and $B$ are complex numbers, $B \neq 0$. Prove that  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{A}{B}. $$

I have a proof. However, I have made certain assumptions which I would like to verify.

**Assumption 1:** If I define $f_1(0) = 0 \text{ and } = f \text{ otherwise}$, and define $g_1$ in a similar fashion, then $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}.$$

**Assumption 2:** I say $f_1(x) = f_1(0) + xf_1'(y_1)$, $g_1(x) = g_1(0) + xg_1'(y_2)$ for some $y_1 \text{ and } y_2 \text{ in } (0,x)$. This assumes, that the mean value theorem is applicable for complex valued functions, and can be used in this way.

Are these assumptions correct? What is a suitable resource for someone reading Baby Rudin to get help on mean value theorem for complex valued functions?

Comment: Why not follow the hint in the book?

Comment: I don't think your mean value theorem is true. There is some $y_r$ where the real part satisfies of $f$ satisfies the real mean value theorem, and another $y_i$ where the imaginary part satisfies the mean value theorem, but there is no reason for there the be one $y$ where both are true.

Comment: For instance, when $f(t)=t^3+t^2i.$ Then given $x\in (0,1)$, $f_1(x)=xf_1'(y_1)$ . would mean that $x^2+xi=3y_1^2+2y_1i$ for some $y_1.$ This gives $y_1=\frac{1}{2}x$ and thus $\frac{3}{4}x^2=x^2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you. So, in general, the mean value theorem can be applied to the different components of a vector valued function (keeping in mind that the points we get for each component might be different)? 

Also, Is the first assumption correct?

Comment: The first assumption is necessarily correct because limits do not care about the value of the function at a specific point, but rather in the vicinity (assuming of course that the limit exists).